# Can't connect to mysql server from command prompt [Laravel]

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I've updated the .env file with my server database data (not localhost), but I can't connect to it via command prompt.

```
DB_HOST=vps.sitename.com
DB_DATABASE=name_of_my_database
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

When I try to access that database from the command line like so:

```
mysql -umyusername -pmypassword
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
Access denied for user 'mysuername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Do you know any solutions for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` command does not use the `.env` file, only Laravel does. If you don't pass the hostname to the command, it will try to connect to `localhost` as you can see from the error message. You can pass that to the command via the `-h` or `--host` option like so:

```
mysql -h vps.sitename.com -umyusername -pmypassword
```

You also need to make sure that the MySQL server on `vps.sitename.com` allows remote connections and that the user `myusername` is allowed to connect from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the credentials in .env file with your server does not mean you can access the DB if localhost is not added/granted access in MySQL, as the mysql command doesn't even use the .env file in the first place.

You would need to GRANT ACCESS to the 'mysuername'@'localhost' in MySQL like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'localhost';
```

then don't forget to flush privileges like:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

This assumes that you created the 'myusername'@'localhost';

Otherwise, you need to do the following:

```
CREATE USER 'myusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

And then don't forget to bind your address in my.cnf in order to access remotely, if applicable, such as:

```
#Replace xxx with your IP Address 
bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This should do it.

Hope everything works out for you.

Comment: What you've just described will not work when connecting remotely. You've just described hot to define a user that can connect locally, and the question clearly states that the intent is to connect to a remote server.

Comment: Please READ my entire response! You would need to bind the address. And taking people's time to provide you with responses should always be regarded as a positive, to penalize someone for taking time out to help others only hinders any initiatives to help out again!

Comment: No need to get angry. You've edited your response a few seconds **after** I've posted my comment so I couldn't of had read **all** of it at that time.

Comment: I am not angry, far from it, considering I do manage 1000+ servers, figured I share some help, I edited and reedited my responses as I have a tendency to press ENTER as I type, and it posts my unfinished reply. Again, action of helping others should not be penalized, did you not get anything from my reply? If so, then I think it would be appropriate to reflect a positive, otherwise, next time people will be reluctant in helping you out or share their perspective with you. I am just here to try to hel out fellow developers and devops. We all supplement one another with difference experiences.

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstood, but my intention was not to discourage you in any way. It's just that your initial answer (before the edits) seemed like it was posted without you reading the question properly, and that happens more than you think and leads to bad answers. The down vote and comment was to draw your attention at the fact that your answer might be incorrect or lacking, and as you can see once you fixed that the down vote is gone.

Comment: My apologies of course, I just began contributing back to the community after years of benefiting from it, so I am still getting the hang of it as I type, I do have a tendency to press the "enter" key, and when I do, it appears that my unfinished replies get posted, so, I immediately click edit, and so on. Thank you for you clarification, and I hope I've clarified my perspective as well.